# Open TFS document directly in Word from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ms-office

Our project documents are currently maintained using TFS. Visual Studio (2013) allows me to view all the checked in documents through the Team Explorer window, under Documents.

In Team Explorer, when I double click a document, it first opens up an Internet Explorer window, which downloads a copy of the server file. I have to then open up the document manually using Word/Excel etc. which then gives me the option to Check Out.

Involving Internet Explorer to open up a file seems really convoluted. Is there any way to configure/launch the appropriate Office program directly from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: was fairly obvious if I'd looked properly.

Team Explorer -> Documents -> Right click on document -> Edit